# Swift circular button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to create a button that has the shape of a circle with an image inside of it. The button itself is added on the Storyboard interface.

Here is my code:

```
imageButton.frame = CGRect(x: 160, y: 160, width: 160, height: 160)
imageButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * imageButton.bounds.size.width
imageButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
imageButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
imageButton.clipsToBounds = true
imageButton.setBackgroundImage(userImg, for: .normal)
```

However, the button has the shape of a rectangle and the picture is not being displayed properly, i.e. it is stretched the wrong way.

Any suggestions on how to fix this will be appreciated.

[image: Output]

Comment: Please show the output, I mean attached the screenshot of result.

Comment: Code seems OK. How are you adding the button to view? Also show the initialization of button.

Comment: imageButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES; try this property otherwise your code is ok.

Comment: Late reply. This seems like a constraint issue. Did you constraint imageView so that it stretches with the screen? ie. going from portrait to lanscape or is your imageView inside a stackView that also stretches with the screen. The problem here is your width is stretched but not your height hence you get the pill effect.

Answer (score 4):

Your code seems working fine, there is not issue with your code, you've shared in your question.

Here I tried that:

```
let imageButton = UIButton()
imageButton.frame = CGRect(x: 160, y: 160, width: 160, height: 160)
imageButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * imageButton.bounds.size.width
imageButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
imageButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
imageButton.clipsToBounds = true
imageButton.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "2"), for: .normal)

//imageButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "2"), for: .normal)

self.view.addSubview(imageButton)
```

Result:

[image]

Try to check, other functionality of your code, affecting your button.

Comment: Yes right code is prefect. may be there is some other issue.

Comment: The problem seems to be the constraints. When I delete all constraints, the button is really a circle.
How would I position the button to be in the center of the frame then? Or can I add constraints from outside?

Comment: Great, you did not mention in your question, that button had constraint also... You can use constraint but for that you need to enable autotranslate mask for constraint programtically.